# Get numeric part of string column and cast to integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

The question is pretty simple actually, I just couldn't figure it out. There is a
Fifa Dataset that I use, and I'd like to convert all `weight` column to integer. so: first I drop the `lbs`, then I convert to integer.

```
fifa["Weight"].head()
           
    0    159lbs
    1    183lbs
    2    150lbs
    3    168lbs
    4    154lbs
    Name: Weight, dtype: object


fifa.Weight = [int(x.strip("lbs")) if type(x)==str else x for x in fifa.Weight]
```

I know that I could use this but I don't want to.

```
fifa_weight =[]

for i in fifa["Weight"]:

    if(type(i)==str):

        fifa_weight.append(int(i.strip("lbs")))

## There are some missing values in the Weight column that's why I use type(i)==str.
```

I get the values inside of the `fifa["Weight"]` column and try to put it inside the `fifa_weight` column but I wasn't able to change the columns(because of missing values) so.. how can I do that with for loop? I want my `fifa["Weight"]` column to be full of integers.

Comment: wow.. can't believe the solution is that easy! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
   Weight
0  159lbs
1  183lbs
2  150lbs
3  168lbs
4  154lbs
```

you can shave off the last three characters and then convert the strings to integers via

```
>>> df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].str[:-3].astype(int)
>>> df
   Weight
0     159
1     183
2     150
3     168
4     154
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> fifa
   Weight
0  159lbs
1  183lbs
2  150lbs
3  168lbs
4  154lbs

fifa["Weight"] = fifa["Weight"].str.replace("lbs", "")
```

and then

```
fifa["Weight"] = fifa["Weight"].astype(float)
```

If you have Empty cells in the Weight's Columns, then fill it first with something like a placeholder (like -9999) or something and then try the above;